# Angular6: How to hide & show the fieldset using by select option?

Tags: angular

I am using angular6. In that I want to disable and enable the fieldset. I need initially don't show the fieldset and then show after selecting option in dropdown list.

Comment: What is your attempt? Provide some code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use ngIf with a variable(false) in the fieldset, on the selection you can change it to true.

```
<fieldset *ngIf="flag">
.....
...
</fieldset>
```

initially the flag value will be false

```
<select (change)="onChange($event.target.value)">
    <option *ngFor="let i of devices">{{i}}</option>
</select>

onChange(deviceValue) {
    console.log(deviceValue);
    this.flag = true
}
```

Comment: thanks! its working fine what I expected

Comment: please mark as answer if it is working

Answer (score 0):

**HTML:**

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <select (change)="onChange($event)" name="sel2">
           <option *ngFor="let c of countries">{{c.name}}</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
<br>
<div class="row" *ngIf="showSubmit">
  <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
     <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Component ts:**

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit { 
          showSubmit: any;
          countries = [
            { id: 1, name: "United States" },
            { id: 2, name: "Australia" },
            { id: 3, name: "Canada" },
            { id: 4, name: "France" },
            { id: 5, name: "England" }
          ];
          selectedValue = "France";      

  onChange(event) {
    if (event.target.value === "England") {
      this.showSubmit =true;
    } else {
      this.showSubmit =false;
    }
}
```

Working Demo : [Stakblitz with full Form](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-du5hbj)